# jquery=>Sending data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Iam working on adding an event planner to my Html form ,
and i cant figure out how to pass this data ("meetup","startEvent","break") from html to my Database .
ive used jQuery to show the data on my browser console like this and it work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bang').on("click", function(){
    $("#editable > li").each(function(){

    $e=($(this).text());
    console.log($e);
```

but i cant get it to send to another page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bang').on("click", function(){
    $("#editable > li").each(function(){

    $e=($(this).text());
    console.log($e);



    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {
         url: "test.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {$e},
        success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
```

Comment: `data: { value: $e },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery('#bang').on("click", function () {

  var data = [];

  jQuery("#editable > li").each(function () {
    data.push(jQuery(this).text());
  });

 console.log(data);

 jQuery.post('test.php', data).done(function () {
    console.log('Done!');
  }).fail(function () {
    console.log('Nopo!');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="editable">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>out</li>
</ul>

<button id="bang">bang!</button>
```